# Why do users troll questions without answering?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, comments

I notice it quite often. Someone will ask a question, and rather than submit an answer to the question said user will critique every other users answer. They may post a short answer in the comments for the question, but that's as far as they are willing to go. I just don't understand it.

You'd think if they are so interested, they would submit their own answer. Does anyone have some insight on this behavior?

Comment: There are plenty of users that try to help a user bang his post into shape so it becomes something worthwhile to keep around and help hundreds of programmers in years to come.  You call it trolling, others call it helping.  Come to think of it, you probably think I'm a troll.  Well, thanks for the compliment.

Comment: Pointing out what is wrong with other answers is not the same as having the solution (or having time to state it as a full answer), but is still useful as it saves readers from wasting time on proposals which are either unworkable or will lead to poor results.

Comment: Every once in a while, I'll see a performance question with 5 or 6 answers - all of which are obviously wrong. But I can't answer it myself because I either 1) don't know the answer, 2) too lazy, 3) don't have the right environment setup. In which case, I'll post a speculative answer as a comment.

Comment: @Mysticial - That's understandable, the question is more about putting comments in multiple answers :)

Comment: @EternalHour Yes, and I'll also comment on those obviously wrong answers. But I stop short of downvoting since that tends to invite revenge downvotes. ([this being my most recent one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979880/odd-results-when-comparing-c-overhead-on-old-new-cpu#comment42495153_26980315))

Comment: @Mysticial - I can see doing that, but what about stating an opinion?

Comment: @EternalHour Opinion of what?

Comment: So, when commenting on an obviously wrong answer, in my opinion it's best to present facts as to why the answer is incorrect (documentation?). But, if the commenter is stating their opinion of why the answer is not correct I consider that not constructive and lowers the quality of the content.

Comment: @EternalHour You also have to take into account that there are a lot of things in programming that *are* subjective (especially when it comes to "good practice"). A comment that says something can be considered bad practice is still constructive (though certainly an opinion).

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - That's a very good point, I agree.

Comment: This what you call 'trolling' is (probably) called 'review queue' (those auto-comments)

Comment: Nah, because when I've seen people do this, they will comment on multiple answers. Kind of surprised more people haven't noticed this.

Answer (score 24):

To answer the general question: *You don't have to be able to, or want to, post an answer in order to know when other posts are crap and need critiquing.*

I'll occasionally do this on homework dump questions where the answers are equally bad code-dumps.

A code-only answer to a homework question helps no one, and I say so; but don't post my own answer because the question was unclear; or because I don't want to do the OPs homework.

In general, my critiquing of a post doesn't mean I know the answer; or even would answer (in the homework case). That doesn't stop me from knowing when something is crap though.

Side note: This approach can work! Just today this happened: [c# windows form how Show 1line 2 text box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27000657/c-sharp-windows-form-how-show-1line-2-text-box/27001057#comment42533103_27001057) and the posters improved their content (I deleted the comments as they were obsolete).

Comment: That makes sense, I would hope nobody would do someones homework for them. Maybe it is as simple as trying to improve content.

Comment: @EternalHour: That is literally the reason that we are all here... Well, except for the help vampires.

Answer (score 4):

This entire question is based on a frustratingly commonplace yet blatantly false premise: that you must both know and submit an answer before you're "allowed" to have any other interaction with a question. What nonsense!

As for people who are not sufficiently "interested" to write a full answer, well… answering properly takes time. And, as you know, we all give our time freely. Perhaps right now I don't feel like I want to spend five or ten minutes writing a proper answer? Perhaps I wish to do something different with my time.

As for people who go ahead anyway and write little "mini-answers" or "tips" in the comments section, well… you know [how I feel about those](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247446/155739).